# Should I fix factual mistake in question body if someone point on it in comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

Someone found factual error in my question, pointed on it and provided other useful information. Should I edit question to fix it? How can I attribute commentator besides upvoting useful comment?

Comment: 1. Yes you should, assuming it wasn't actually the answer; and 2. Upvoting the comment is fine - alternatively, you could ask the commenter to make the edit, so their name appears in the post history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't change a question if it invalidates any of the answers. I.e. if one of the answers already says that you have a factual error in the question in this case.

If that's not the case and changing it would not invalidate the question entirely then do edit the question and in the edit summary explain what you changed and that you did it because of `<name>`'s suggestion.

Comment: Actually, an answer pointing out that error in the question, as long as that error is just incidental to the question, does not and should not fix that error, unless keeping it actually makes the Q&A-pair *more* valuable. It should still be silently corrected, with a notification of the answerers / edit of the answers which picked on it instead of clarifying the question.

Answer (score 6):

You should fix it in your question *if it wasn't the cause of, or didn't contribute to your problem*.

If it did cause or contribute to the issue then by altering your question the issue disappears, therefore there is no question any more.

> How can I attribute commentator besides upvoting useful comment?

I presume you mean *reward* rather than *attribute*. The simple answer is you cannot - all they did was leave a comment. You could go and find an answer of theirs that was worth an up vote if you are feeling motivated, but by their nature comments cannot gather reward (except for some badges).

If you did mean *attribute* then you can refer to the comment in an answer (or your question) by copying the link from the timestamp - as I've done for [this comment from jonsharpe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295536/should-i-fix-factual-mistake-in-question-body-if-someone-point-on-it-in-comment/295538#comment199814_295536).

Comment: Just be aware that such comments often become obsolete if acted upon: The reward was being heeded, and most should be pruned (after being flagged by the recipient, or preferably directly by the commenter).